# How to get multiple counts from room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I want to return multiple counts from `Room` Select query in `android`.
My query is like

```
Select Count(CASE WHEN x = '0' or x = '2'), Count(Case when a = '33' or a = '23') FROM my_table WHERE id=10
```

I want above query to return something as list which will contain values of both the above `Count()` function. This can be easily done using `SQLite` but I want to use it in `room`.

Comment: This link does not tell me about the return type of the function in Room's DAO

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question. Please take a look at my answer, hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give names to the counts and return them as a class, like:

```kotlin
data class MyCounts(
  @ColumnInfo(name = "first_count")
  val firstCount: Int,

  @ColumnInfo(name = "second_count")
  val secondCount: Int
)

@Dao
interface MyDao {
  @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) as first_count, COUNT(*) as second_count from my_table")
  suspend fun getMyCounts(): MyCounts
}
```

Comment: I just found the same solution 5 minutes back  :D...thanks for helping out :)