# How to get counts of records based on a column values in a single SQLite query using Room in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I have this table which holds records of say Students in Room database which I am using, I have tried some SQl queries to fetch what I want as described below but that's not working.

Table: Students

```
 

id  name    grade      age
1   John     Good       10
2   Jan    Average      11
3   Bob      Good        9
4   Peter    Low        11
5   Jack   Average      10
```

Now, I want to get counts of records based on the grades, so for the above records, the query will return counts based on grades as below

```
 
Good - 2
Average - 2
Low - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

sql syntax,

```
SELECT grade, COUNT(grade)
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY grade;
```

Comment: Great! This was helpful to construct the base query. Though @simon5678's answer added the part of the solution which mattered to get the result as a list of counts.

Answer (score 1):

```
class QueryResult{
    String grade;
    @Embedded
    int total_count;

}
```

```
@Query("SELECT grade, COUNT(grade) as total_count FROM Students GROUP BY grade")
List<QueryResult> queryGroupedGrade();
```

Comment: You answer was very much near to my solution, but I faced some compile time error due to @Embedded annotation which was breaking some key constraint of my Room database tables. I ended up doing the solution in following answer which was perfect for me.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382612/how-to-get-multiple-counts-from-room-database), so overall my solution consisted of the mix of these answers and some minor mofications.

Answer (score 1):

Give another solution. If you are using kotlin, you can use `groupBy` function.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html

Demo code:

1. Get data from SQLite

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Students")
abstract fun queryGrade(): List<QueryResult>
```

2. Fetch the data and group it by grade

```
fun fetchGrade() {
    return dao.queryGrade().run{
        this.groupBy {it.grade}
    }
}
```

Comment: is it efficient?

Comment: I can't tell you is it more efficient or not, but you can reuse data in many places or collections (ex. groupBy, sortBy, filter...etc) and only require database I/O one time.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be useful to other developers, so I am posting my final solution which I got from the combination of the above answers as I mentioned in the comments to @simon5678

```
@Query("SELECT grade, COUNT(grade) as total_count FROM Students GROUP BY grade")
fun queryGroupedGrade(): List<QueryResult>

data class QueryResult(

    var grade: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_count")
    var total_count: Int = 0
)
```